# php -i does not result local .ini file?

Tags: php, ini

I'm logged in as the user and attempting to perform:

```
# php -i |grep Scan
```

My hope, is to see the additional .ini file being called/referenced when parsing the PHP for this directory.

However, "Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)", I'm not sure why it's not returning the additional .ini file even though it exists.

```
user@domain.tld [~/domains/domain.tld/public_html]# ls -la *.ini
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 23 Feb 24 19:15 php.ini

user@domain.tld [~/domains/domain.tld/public_html]# php -i |grep Scan
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
```

Any input on this would be helpful.

Comment: That does not mean your current directory. You can set another directory in which PHP will check for config files.

Comment: You may be interested in [`.user.ini files`](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php)